# import statement in empythoned doesn't work in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, google-chrome-extension, empythoned

I am using javascript generated by [Empythoned](https://github.com/replit/empythoned) to create a chrome [extension](https://github.com/kracekumar/offline-python). Python `import` doesn't work in chrome extension where as it works in web application. Here is the [demo](https://github.com/kracekumar/test-empythoned).

### Sample code:

### Web App

### Input

```
import collections
print collections
```

### Output

```
<module 'collections' from '/lib/python2.7/collections.py'>
```

### Chrome Extension

### Input

```
import collections
```

### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 8, in <module>
from _collections import deque, defaultdict
ImportError: Could not evaluate dynamic lib: //lib/python2.7/_collections.so
```

Is it something to do with chrome extension handling JS ?

Answer (score 1):

Empythoned is trying to `eval()` code, and Chrome by default restricts `eval()` from being used in extensions.

More details on the Content Security Policy can be found here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

If you add this line relaxing the security policy to your extension's `manifest.json`, you should be able to import those modules:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

As the documentation warns, `eval()` is a notorious XSS attack vector, so you should be careful when allowing it in your extensions.